# Deleting entries in STL vector

Tags: c++, stl

I want to clean up the threads which pointers are stored in STL vector. I am doing it as below. Is this right way of doing as i am deleting entries while looping thourgh vector or there is better way to do this.

Please suggest.

```
template <typename threadFuncParamT >
bool ThreadPool<threadFuncParamT>::KillSleepingThreads()
{
  if(m_vecThreads.size() != 0)
  {
      for (; std::vector< ThreadWrapper < threadFuncParamT>* >::iterator itrCollThreads !=  values.end(); )
      {
    ThreadWrapper < threadFuncParamT> *pWrapper = m_vecThreads.back();
            m_vecThreads.pop_back();
            delete pWrapper;
      } // for loop
  } // if condition
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do use a smart pointer. Use `std::unique_ptr`or another if that's not supported.

Answer (score 4):

If you're allowed to use C++11, then make it cute:

```
for (auto it = m_vecThreads.begin() ; it !=  m_vecThreads.end(); ++it )
{
     delete *it;
}
m_vecThreads.clear();
```

You can make it even more cute (in C++11, of course - thanks to @celtschk's comment):

```
for (auto & ptr: m_vecThreads) //it is called range-based for loop
{ 
    delete ptr; 
}
m_vecThreads.clear();
```

---

Or if you're *not* allowed to use C++11, then replace `auto` (in the *first* `for` loop) with this:

```
  typename std::vector<ThreadWrapper<threadFuncParamT*>::iterator
//^^^^^^^^ you've to typename as well
```

Note that you've to use `typename` as well, for `iterator` is a dependent name.

Also, the following is not needed, remove it from your code:

```
if(m_vecThreads.size() != 0) // not needed!
```

Comment: With C++11, you can even make it more cute: `for (auto ptr: m_vecThreads) { delete ptr; } m_vecThreads.clear();`

Comment: even more cute. std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> threads; Not deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your function:

```
     for(size_t i = 0; i < m_vecThreads.size(); ++i)
     {
        delete m_vecThreads[i];
     }
     m_vecThreads.clear();
```

Comment: It's generally considered better form to use iterators to iterate a collection, hence the term "iterator."

Comment: @ChrisParton you're right for general cases. But in the case, we could  get better performance for random access and don't have to worry about the iterator invalidation problem compared to the original version. For me, I prefer to std::for_each. The reason is that it could applied to most of the standard containers and the compilers usually give optimized std::for_each for random access iterators.

Comment: @BruceAdi: Invalidated iterators isn't a worry here. If it were, your increment logic wouldn't be what it is.

Comment: Isn't it a little contradictory to talk about performance, when you call `vector.size()` for every pass of your loop? It is trivial to restructure it. However the overhead of `delete`ing is so high that this is meaningless in the first place, so you can just use `iterators` and `std::for_each`, or range-based `for` for better readability anyway.

Comment: from above discussion it seems we have performance issue as we have to adjust vector always after every deletion, how we can achieve this using for_each and iterators

Comment: It would be possible for the compiler to optimise away the repeated calls to `m_vecThreads.size()`, would it not?

Comment: @ChrisParton yes. For most of the libraries,std::vector::size is inlined for better performance. Note that this is not mandatory to the library author.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot more complicated then it needs to. If you are really trying to just delete every item in the vector, just `delete` each item then clear the entire vector.

```
for(std::vector<ThreadWrapper<threadFuncParamT*>>::iterator
        i = m_vecThreads.begin();
    i != m_vecThreads.end();
    ++i)
{
    delete *i;
}

m_vecThreads.clear();
```

As an aside, it's usually a better practice to have a vector of smart pointers (eg `boost::shared_ptr`) than having to explicitly delete items.